# how personalize login in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I already tried to follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users), but I did not succeed.
I need to add a condition to the original login system

I've tried the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'type' => 'cliente'])) {

            dd('autenticate');   

        }
    }

}
```

my route

```
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

the erro:

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable: email in /var/www...
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

**----------- RESOLVED -----------**

I do not know if it's the safest way, but it worked this way:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{

    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $input=$request->all();
    $password=$input['password'];
    $email=$input['email'];

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'type'=>'cliente'])) {

        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticate');
```

Comment: show us the `login` function.

Comment: @Wreigh the function login does not exist in controller LoginController that I'm manipulating; This function is within the class AuthenticatesUsers which is inside the vendor folder

Comment: also, what is the error or problem? what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: the erro: ErrorException: Undefined variable: email - actually the email variable is not defined. But in the documentation example the variable was not defined either. probably an error in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the credentials. You don't need a seperate `authenticate` method. In `LoginController` override this function that is in trait :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;    //*****add this

class LoginController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    **
    * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return array
    */
    protected function credentials(Request $request){
        return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['type' => 'cliente']);
    }
}
```

Hope it's helpful.